# Use Java 10 with Spring MVC 5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-10

Currently I am using Java 8 and Spring MVC 4. I want to upgrade java into 10 and spring into 5. So **Is Spring MVC 5 is compatible with Java 10 ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They added support for JDK9 features, most notably the `Flow` API (cf their [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/overview.html#overview)). And, as far as I know, it seems compatible with JDK10.

The language changes in java 10 are pretty minor and retro-compatibles. I'm using spring 5 with java 10 and still haven't noticed any regression.

Comment: Means i can use `java 10` with `spring mvc 5`

Comment: Yes you can. But that's more of an issue of retro-compatibility on the java side rather than Spring. Java 9 brought the concept of modules which could be troublesome with libraries but java 10 is fairly small. Meaning : if it works with java9, it'll probably work with java 10. (Except when the jdk10 bugs :))

Answer (score 1):

Looking to the service [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) in full version it is possible to choose between java 8 and java 10, so I think that it is fully compatible.